# Oracle date formatting error - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, to-date, to-char

I am trying to execute a simple query (ORACLE DB)  to display two date columns (START_TIME & END_TIME) along with total counts along with percentage and filtered by a month followed by year the data type defined in the for the two date fields in db as date, i am trying to display the data in the below format

**sample data no time stamp**

```
start_time - 01.12.2020 
end_time - 02.12.2020
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
to_char(cast(START_TIME as date),'YYYY') as START_BY_YEAR ,
to_char(cast(END_TIME as date),'YYYY') as END_BY_YEAR ,
to_char(cast(START_TIME as date),'MM.YYYY')as START_BY_MONTH,
to_char(cast(END_TIME as date),'MM.YYYY') as END_BY_MONTH,
to_char(cast(START_TIME as date),'DD.MM.YYYY') as START_BY_DAY,
to_char(cast(END_TIME as date),'DD.MM.YYYY') as END_BY_DAY,
COUNT(*) as count,
round(100*ratio_to_report(count(*)) over (), 4) percentage  
FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
WHERE to_char(cast(START_TIME as date),'MM.YYYY')='12.2020'
and to_char(cast(END_TIME as date),'MM.YYYY')='12.2020'
GROUP BY 
START_BY_YEAR,
END_BY_YEAR,
START_BY_MONTH,
END_BY_MONTH,
START_BY_DAY,
END_BY_DAY
order by 
START_BY_YEAR desc,
END_BY_YEAR desc,
START_BY_MONTH desc,
END_BY_MONTH desc,
START_BY_DAY desc,
END_BY_DAY desc
```

I am getting error message

```
ORA-00904: "END_BY_DAY": invalid identifier
```

904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
     *Cause:
     *Action:
     Error at Line: 19 Column: 1

where exactly i am getting error is not clear

**expected result set**

```
START_BY_YEAR END_BY_YEAR START_BY_MONTH END_BY_MONTH START_BY_DAY END_BY_DAY
2012          2012        12.2012        12.2012      01.12.2020   02.12.2020
```

Please note i have expanded the code for easily readable purpose.

Suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the error, you have to remove the aliases from the `GROUP BY` clause.
Also, if your table has `date` columns, you don't need `CASTs` and the query can be re-wrtten as:

```
SELECT 
    to_char(START_TIME,'YYYY') START_BY_YEAR ,
    to_char(END_TIME,'YYYY') END_BY_YEAR ,
    to_char(START_TIME,'MM.YYYY') START_BY_MONTH,
    to_char(END_TIME,'MM.YYYY') END_BY_MONTH,
    to_char(START_TIME,'DD.MM.YYYY') START_BY_DAY,
    to_char(END_TIME,'DD.MM.YYYY') END_BY_DAY,
    COUNT(*) as count,
    round(100*ratio_to_report(count(*)) over (), 4) percentage  
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE to_char(START_TIME,'MM.YYYY')='12.2020'
  and to_char(END_TIME,'MM.YYYY')='12.2020'
GROUP BY 
  to_char(START_TIME,'YYYY') ,
  to_char(END_TIME,'YYYY') ,
  to_char(START_TIME,'MM.YYYY') ,
  to_char(END_TIME,'MM.YYYY') ,
  to_char(START_TIME,'DD.MM.YYYY') ,
  to_char(END_TIME,'DD.MM.YYYY') 
order by 
    START_BY_YEAR desc,
    END_BY_YEAR desc,
    START_BY_MONTH desc,
    END_BY_MONTH desc,
    START_BY_DAY desc,
    END_BY_DAY desc
```

With a table like this:

```
create table table_name as
(
    select date '2020-12-01' start_time,
           date '2020-12-02' end_time
    from dual
);
```

The query gives:

```
START_BY_YEA END_BY_YEAR  START_BY_MON END_BY_MONTH START_BY_DAY END_BY_DAY   COUNT PERCENTAGE
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ----- ----------
2020         2020         12.2020      12.2020      01.12.2020   02.12.2020       1        100
1 row selected.
```

Comment: I have already mentioned above the data type is date , u gave tried to re run but again i am facing error ORA-00904: "END_BY_DAY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 19 Column: 1

Comment: Just edited to show a complete working query, simplified

Comment: Many Thanks it's working, I got the understanding of the error

Answer (score 0):

First check the partial result of:

```
select cast(END_TIME as date),'DD.MM.YYYY') as END_BY_DAY
FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
```

from the results you can learn about the NLS format of your machin and wrap it with custom to_char format.